# Opencart - Need Product options ( quantity ) on home page

Tags: php, opencart

Opencart - Need Product options (weight, quantity & Size with live price update) on category list & home page and mobile compatibility. weight already done
check attached image for reference[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm which OC version you are using, so that I can help you with the solutions. And also are you using any theme or just looking for default theme.

Comment: thanx for rplying @PradeepKumarReddyThatipally.
oc 1.5.6
default version.

Comment: @AmolNavsupe Did you get the issue sorted? Please help as we are stuck at the same issue.

Comment: @Lal no sir not done but time delivery done. please help me on that.